# Proof of Gruss inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, inequality

I've been reading articles that use the Gruss inequality for some time now, but I can't seem to find a proof of it anywhere. The only source I could find that actually has the proof is the original paper by Gruss, but the article costs $40 and I don't want to pay that much. The statement is as follows:

Let $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be integrable functions on $[a,b]$ such that
$$
\phi \leq f(x) \leq \Phi, \enspace \gamma \leq g(x) \leq \Gamma, \enspace \forall x \in [a,b], \enspace \phi,\Phi,\gamma,\Gamma \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Then the following inequality holds:
$$
\left| T(f,g) \right| \leq \frac{1}{4}(\Phi-\phi)(\Gamma-\gamma),
$$

where

$$
T(f,g) := \frac{1}{b-a} \int\limits_a^b \! f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d} x - \frac{1}{b-a} \int\limits_a^b \! f(x)\,\mathrm{d} x \cdot
\frac{1}{b-a} \int\limits_a^b \! g(x)\,\mathrm{d} x.
$$

I've tried following these steps of the proof but I'm stuck on the very first one:

First show that $T(f,f)\geq 0$, $T(g,g)\geq 0$ and $T^2(f,g)\leq T(f,f)T(g,g)$. Then show that $T(f,f)\leq \frac{1}{4}(\Phi-\phi)^2$ and $T(g,g)\leq \frac{1}{4}(\Gamma-\gamma)^2$. Combining these steps then yields the desired inequality. I know that the policy of this site is that you should show your work first, but right now the only thing I could show is a failed attempt at using Cauchy's or Holder's inequality to prove the statement.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

I found a proof so I'll post it if anyone gets curious. Firstly, we use this identity proven by K.A.Andreief, which states that the Chebyshev functional can be written as

$$
T(f,g) = \frac{1}{2(b-a)^2} \int\limits_a^b \! \int\limits_a^b \! (f(x)-f(y))(g(x)-g(y)) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} y.
$$

Now that it is written this way, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for double integrals we have

$$
T^2(f,g)\leq T(f,f)T(g,g).
$$

By $A(f)$ we denote the arithmetical integral mean:

$$
A(f) = \frac{1}{b-a} \int\limits_a^b \! f(x) \mathrm{d} x,
$$

so by the inequality between the arithmetic and quadratic mean we obtain

$$
T(f,f)=A(f^2)-A^2(f) \geq 0.
$$

One can easily see that the following identity is also true

$$
T(f,f) = (\Phi-A(f))(A(f)-\phi) - \frac{1}{b-a} \int\limits_a^b \! (\Phi-f(x))(f(x)-\phi) \mathrm{d} x,
$$

which then implies

$$
T(f,f) \leq (\Phi-A(f))(A(f)-\phi).
$$

In the same way we can show that

$$
T(g,g) \leq (\Gamma-A(g))(A(g)-\gamma)
$$

is valid. Combining previous steps, we obtain

$$
T^2(f,g) \leq (\Phi-A(f))(A(f)-\phi)(\Gamma-A(g))(A(g)-\gamma).
$$

Finally, by the A-G inequality, it is obvious that

$$
(\Phi-A(f))(A(f)-\phi)\leq \frac{1}{4}(\Phi-\phi)^2, \enspace (\Gamma-A(g))(A(g)-\gamma)\leq \frac{1}{4}(\Gamma-\gamma)^2
$$

so we have

$$
T^2(f,g) \leq \frac{1}{16} (\Phi-\phi)^2(\Gamma-\gamma)^2,
$$

that is

$$
|T(f,g)|\leq \frac{1}{4}(\Phi-\phi)(\Gamma-\gamma).
$$

Comment: Well, you can simplify a little by assuming $a = 0, b = 1$, via the substitution $au + b = x$. Then showing that $T(f,f) \ge 0$ amounts to showing $\int f^2 - \int f \int f \ge 0$. If you think of $f$ as a random variable, the LHS is (I think) equivalent to $E[F^2] - E[f]^2$, which is the variance of $f$, which is always nonnegative.

Comment: $(+1)$ *I learned something new today!* :-$)$

Comment: I added the proof so maybe you'll find it entertaining too. :) @Lucian

Comment: @implicati0n The inequality that $T(f,f) \leq \frac{1}{4}(\Phi - \phi)^2$ is also called Popoviciu's variance inequality